Astable 555 timer staying on
I've recently followed Ben Eater's tutorial on how to make an astable 555 timer with parts that were just hanging around my house, albeit with a NE555P instead of his HA17555.
I did not have a 10kOhm resistor, so I skipped directly to using a 1-3 MOhm resistor wired in series with a 1kOhm resistor, as he did.
I also did not have 0.1uF capacitors, but I do not think that would affect anything because in the video, it is shown that the timer continues to oscillate without the capacitors.
Otherwise, I followed his tutorial. However, despite that, the LED would continue to stay on, regardless on how I trimmed the variable resistor.

The capacitor is 1uF 100VDC, the variable resistor is 1-3MOhm, and the chip is a NE555P (Since jpg compression removed the label on the chip).
(From eater.net)

The timer schematic is the top left timing module, but with pin 3 connected to an LED, in series to a 330 ohm resistor, connected to ground.
How do I fix this problem?

The cause was that I accidentally connected pin 7 to ground, not the 5V source.
